# DISTINCT gives duplicate values

Tags: duplication, oracle-19c, distinct

Can it be considered a bug? This query gives duplicate values despite DISTINCT:

```
select distinct '1'
from 
(
select *
from dual
connect by level <= 10
)
order by dbms_random.value
fetch first 10 rows only
```

I understand it creates additional column with random values and uses distinct with two columns, but still I expect to get unique values.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me-- adding a `fetch first n rows only` clause shouldn't change the number of rows returned (https://dbfiddle.uk/EgS0a4FZ).  Have you submitted a bug report to Oracle to confirm?

Comment: The problem isn't just in fetch.. but in combination order by + fetch, if columns in order by have duplicate values. I haven't submitted a bug. I'm just curious. Group by solves this problem

Comment: This is actually a bug. I wrote to AskTom, they confirmed it.

Answer (score -1):

The subquery that generates the rows from the dual table is not distinct. The DISTINCT keyword in the outer query only eliminates duplicate rows that result from the subquery, but it does not eliminate duplicate values within each row.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '1'
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
)
ORDER BY dbms_random.value
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Subquery is needed to create a table with multiple rows.

Comment: Let's say

create table my_table as select * from dual connect by level <= 10
;
select distinct '1'
from my_table
order by dbms_random.value
fetch first 10 rows only
;